Why the Airflow dag is not getting triggered?
I have attached the code. It's 1st Sept 2024, Sunday, 21:45 UTC. Dag should have triggered. What's the problem with it ? I had to manually trigger it. BTW, rest of the dags are running fine, getting triggered on the scheduled time.
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['abc@abc.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 8, 26),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG("your_random_dag",
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='0 21 * * 0',
          dagrun_timeout=None,
          catchup=False,
          )

begin = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id="BEGIN")

end = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id="END")

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id="your_random_dag",
    bash_command='python3 /scripts/prod/run_me.py' ,
    dag=dag) 
 
begin >> t1 >> end


Because the first interval starts on September the 1est, and will be triggered at the end of the interval. Have a look at data-interval

@vdolez So, in that situation, what should I have entered in Start Date then to have it triggered today, 1st Sept ?

The question should not be "when will the DAG start ?" but instead "what period of time should a DAG run cover ?" The goal of a DAG is usually to perform ETL or ELT operations, this is best done following idempotence principles. Synchronizing DAG runs with database partitions is useful to perform retries at the DAG level and at the task level. Because a partition is only fully available when it has ended, the DAG run corresponding to a partition is executed at the end of the period.

'start_date': datetime(2024, 8, 25), would have triggered the DAG on September the 1st.
